# MacBook Pro doesn't recognize internal SSD

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

A week ago I inserted a USB cable into my MacBook Pro (late 2013) which resulted in the laptop immediately shutting down. After a lot of searching how to boot it up again I had to reset the SMC. After this it booted normally.

A few days later the MacBook Pro started hanging and freezing from time to time.

I decided to do a clean OSX install.
After erasing the disk the SSD has never been detected again. Check the pictures:

[image]
[image]

So right now I'm unable to install OSX... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your hard drive is no longer working properly and needs to be replaced.  However, you can try to diagnose using the [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731).

If hardware problems are indicated or Apple Diagnostics does not recognize your hard drive either, it may be worth looking for a Retail Store or AASP to get it looked at.

If you are still in Apple's hardware coverage, such repair will usually be free of charge.

Comment: It says: no issues found... Going to bring it to Apple, let them figure it out. Any idea how long it would take? I'm a dev so not good to have this taken away.

Comment: It really depends on how busy they are, e.g. how many are already in queue.  Replacing a hard drive itself should not take more than 30-60 minutes once they start to open the computer and have the parts ready.  So, to get the most accurate information is to ask them really.